# Beginning of Sudoku solution: 2 x rspec failing

Tags: ruby, rspec, sudoku

Why is the first test returning 173, not 81 and the second 20, not 9? How can i return the number of arrays from `@cells.each_slice(9).map { |v| v }` - `count` method?

```
class Grid

  attr_reader :cells

  def initialize(puzzle)
    @cells = puzzle.chars.map { |x| (x.to_i) }
  end

  def rows
    @rows = @cells.each_slice(9).map { |v| v }
  end 
end
```

spec

```
 require 'Grid'

  describe Grid do

    context "initialization" do 
      let(:puzzle) { '01500300200010090627
                      00684304900020175010
                      40380003905000900081
                      04086007002503720460
                      0'}
      let(:grid) { Grid.new(puzzle) }

       it 'should have 81 cells' do
        expect(grid.cells.length).to eq(81)
      end

       it 'should have an unsolved first cell' do
        expect(grid.cells.first).to eq(0)
      end

      it 'should have 9 rows' do
        expect(grid.rows).to eq(9)
      end
    end
  end
```

rspec report

```
Grid
  initialization
    should have 81 cells (FAILED - 1)
    should have an unsolved first cell
    should have 9 rows (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) Grid initialization should have 81 cells
     Failure/Error: expect(grid.cells.length).to eq(81)

       expected: 81
            got: 173

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/grid_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Grid initialization should have 9 rows
     Failure/Error: expect(grid.rows).to eq(9)

       expected: 9
            got: 20

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/grid_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00165 seconds
3 examples, 2 failures
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted the numeric string into irb and found where the 173 is coming from:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = '01500300200010090627
irb(main):002:0'                       00684304900020175010
irb(main):003:0'                       40380003905000900081
irb(main):004:0'                       04086007002503720460
irb(main):005:0'                       0'
=> "01500300200010090627\n                      00684304900020175010\n                      40380003905000900081\n                      04086007002503720460\n                      0"
irb(main):006:0> a.length
=> 173
```

As you can see it is including the newlines and spaces. You probably want this:

```
let(:puzzle) { '01500300200010090627' +
               '00684304900020175010' +
               '40380003905000900081' +
               '04086007002503720460' +
               '0' }
```

Regarding `@rows` I am guessing you want

```
@rows = @cells.each_slice(9).to_a
```

but in your test you should have

```
expect(grid.rows.size).to eq(9)
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how i can return the number of arrays from `@rows = @cells.each_slice(9).map { |v| v }`?

Comment: Of course! `to_a` then `.count` return 9. I was over complicating it.Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying my best to get the hang or rspec. What would you suggest for the test? I added `.count` and it rspec throws an error `undefined method count' for 9:Fixnum`

Comment: Got it! `expect(grid.rows.count).to eq (9)`

Answer (score 1):

Do change the line

```
  @cells = puzzle.chars.map { |x| (x.to_i) }
```

as

```
  @cells = puzzle.gsub(/[^0-9]/,'').chars.map { |x| (x.to_i) }
```

Full code :

```
class Grid

  attr_reader :cells

  def initialize(puzzle)
    @cells = puzzle.gsub(/[^0-9]/,'').chars.map { |x| (x.to_i) }
  end

  def rows
    @rows = @cells.each_slice(9).map { |v| v }
  end 
end

s = '01500300200010090627
     00684304900020175010
     40380003905000900081
     04086007002503720460
                      0'
grid = Grid.new(s)
grid.cells.length # => 81
grid.rows.size # => 9
```

Comment: What does this do `gsub(/[^0-9]/,'')`? Tried it and rspec returns 9 arrays in an array.

Comment: Tried it again this morning and it does work. Thanks.

Comment: I've realised that although interesting `gsub(/[^0-9]/,'')` is unnecessary.